# Create columns at runtime in the Kendo UI Angular2 grid

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I am about to start using the Kendo UI Angular2 grid to display a dataset that has a dynamic schema and as a result need to build the grid columns dynamically.  How do I set the grid columns at runtime (programmatically)?

Answer (score 0):

To generate dynamic **OR** run-time column from given result, you have to do some operation on that row data (result) and have to fetch first row from the result and then get each object from that row and prepare column list.

I have already posted answer for custom kendo grid, please refer this link where all the steps are mention: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45506257/6606630

**Note:** Check `SetColumns()` function in above link answer